# How do I simulate autocorrelated count data in R using arima.sim?

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, arima, autocorrelation

I'm trying to simulate a time series of 25 years of autocorrelated count data in R based on the properties of some observed counts. Through model fitting, I've established that the observed data is AR(1) autocorrelated with a lag 1 correlation coeffecient of -0.5 and are overdispersed and best represented by a negative binomial distribution with mean = 10000 and a size parameter of 5.217.

I'm using `arima.sim` to try and simulate the series using the following code:

```
sim = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=-0.5), n=25, rand.gen = rnbinom, mu = 10000, size = 5.217)
sim
```

However, I can't understand why the function returns decimal values, rather than integer counts, and frequently returns negative values, which shouldn't be possible for rnbinom. Additionally, `mean(sim)` is consistently significantly lower than the mean of 10000 specificed in the function. I am clearly not understanding fully what `arima.sim` is doing. I was hoping someone could shed some light and suggest better ways of achieving what I am trying to accomplish?

Thanks for your help, Sam

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76632159/9463489) to an essentially identical question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @jblood94 for providing the link to his [answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631654/simulate-an-ar1-process-that-approximates-a-gamma-distribution/76632159#76632159) which provides a really nice solution to the problem using his `acf.reorder` function provided [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606259/how-to-generate-uniform-distributed-samples-with-given-auto-correlation-function/606457#606457).

I've adapted and simplified the function below to generate a time series of `N` autocorrelated counts drawn from a given negative binomial distribution (specificed by `mu` and `size`).

```
acf.negbin <- function(N, mu, size, alpha, max.iter = 100, tol = 1e-5) {
  
  m = length(alpha)
  
  generate = function(){
   x = sort(rnbinom(N,size=size,mu=mu))
   y <- rnorm(length(x))
   x[rank(stats::filter(y, alpha, circular = TRUE))]
  }
  
  a = generate()
  iter <- 0L
  
  ACF <- function(x) acf(x, lag.max = m - 1, plot = FALSE)$acf[1:m]
  SSE <- function(x,alpha) sum((ACF(x) - alpha)^2)
    
  while ((SSE0 <- SSE(a, alpha)) > tol) {
    if ((iter <- iter + 1L) == max.iter) break
    a1 <- generate()
    if(SSE(a1,alpha) < SSE0) a <- a1
  }
    
  return(a)
  
}
```

As described in the [original post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606259/how-to-generate-uniform-distributed-samples-with-given-auto-correlation-function/606457#606457), the method works by repeatedly drawing samples from the negative binomial distribution and re-ordering them to approximate the desired autocorrelation function given by `alpha`. In the modified function I've moved the random count generation inside the while loop which seems to allow it to more efficiently find a good approximation for short timeseries. You can get a better approximation by increasing the number of iterations (`max.iter`) or reducing the tolerance (`tol`), which is the sum of squared errors between desired `alpha` and observed `alpha` at which a solution is accepted.

Testing shows that it gets very close to the desired time series for my example above

```
set.seed(2023)
x = acf.negbin(25,mu=10000,size=5.217,alpha=c(1,-0.5),max.iter=1000)
plot(x,type='l')
mean(x)
acf(x)$acf[1:2]
```

Thanks again to @jblood94 for the solution, and +1 for each of the original posts!